# ¿Cómo poner títulos en las listas de HTML?

Tags: html, html5

Las listas ordenadas en HTML, ¿poseen una etiqueta para ponerle título?

No me refiero a los títulos: `<h1>`, `<h2>`, ..., `<h6>`, porque si tengo este código:

```html
<h1>Título de la lista</h1>
    <ol>
      <li>Elemento 1</li>
      <li>Elemento 2</li>
      <li>Elemento 3</li>
    </ol>
```

realmente el título del `h1` no está asociado semánticamente a la lista.  Entonces, ¿existe una etiqueta que se pueda usar par identificar semánticamente el título de la lista? Y si no, ¿cómo se puede añadir un título a una lista?

Comment: Hola Reinos, lamentablemente no se entiende. Puedes tratar de explicar un poco mejor a que te refieres?

Comment: Como dices en un comentario existió una etiqueta llamada *list header* `<lh>` pero quedó obsoleta hace mucho ya. Lo mejor es que pongas un encabezado `<h1>`, `<h2>` o el que necesites antes de la lista. Puedes agruparlo todo en un `<section>` para darle una estructura más semántica

Comment: Hola Blonfu, aplique el <section> y me funciono gracias

Comment: @blonfu deberías poner eso como respuesta. Creo que es la única forma correcta de hacerlo en HTML5

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, el problema es que la pregunta esta cerrada de momento por eso lo puse en un comentario. La etiqueta `<lh>` es muy rara y nadie ha entendido la pregunta

Comment: ¿Como lo marco como solucionado?

Comment: @blonfu no me di cuenta de las horas y que tu comentario era posterior. La etiqueta `lh` directamente no existe (no pasó del borrador).

Comment: Creo que llego a existir en HTML3, en HTML4 no creo que estuviera ya. Y parece que se quiso recuperar en HTML5 pero se descartó

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro he estado investigando un poco y tienes razón. HTML3 nunca llego a recomendación y en la version 3.2 no está `<lh>`. En HTML5 no lo veo en ningún borrador, creo que simplemente algunos usuarios pidieron recuperar `<lh>` pero no parece que nunca haya estado en los planes del desarrollo de HTML5

Comment: O con razón, es que igual he usado <lh> pero me lo marcaba el programa, por tal razón fue que vine aquí a buscar solución a mi respuesta.

Comment: El quiere que al igual que a un `input` se le asocia un `label`, que se le asocie un título a una lista

Answer (score 5):

Existió en [HTML3](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/bulletlists.html) una etiqueta llamada `<lh>` (header list) que servía precisamente para poner un encabezado a una lista, aunque la versión que se convirtió en el estándar fue la 3.2 y [ahí](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32) ya no aparece, tampoco en ninguna de las especificaciones posteriores. Aún así en algunas páginas con tutoriales de HTML, y no precisamente antiguas, aparece erróneamente esta etiqueta, a veces incluida como etiqueta válida de HTML5 (quizá de ahí venga la duda de @ReinosRic).

Para poner un encabezado a una lista hay que hacerlo fuera de ésta,  solo los `li` pueden ser hijos directos de un `ol` o `ul`, aunque dentro de los `li` sí pueden ir otras etiquetas pero poner ahí los encabezados rompe con la semántica. Se puede agrupar todo el conjunto en un `section`, por ejemplo, para darle una estructura mas semántica y que quede claro que el título pertenece a la lista:

```
<section> 
  <h2>Título lista</h2> 
  <ul> 
    <li>elemento 1</li>
    <li>elemento 2</li>
    <li>elemento 3</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeramente, una **lista ordenada** sería de esta forma:

```html
    <ol>
      <li>titulo a</li>
      <li>titulo b</li>
      <li>titulo c</li>
    </ol>
```

en cuanto a como agregar titulos, me parece te refieres en realidad a encabezados html:

```html
<h1>Encabezado 1</h1>
<h2>Encabezado 2</h2>
<h3>Encabezado 3</h3>
<h4>Encabezado 4</h4>
<h5>Encabezado 5</h5>
<h6>Encabezado 6</h6>
```

Si deseas agregar un encabezado a una lista ordenada esta sería la forma:

```html
<ol>
    <h1>Elementos</h1>
    <li>Elemento 1</li>
    <li>Elemento 2</li>
    <li>Elemento 3</li>
</ol>
```

---

Comment: Hola, yo mas bien me refiero a que si existe una etiqueta para encabezados de listas.

Comment: ok puedes agregar un encabezado como primer elemento de la lista ordenada, actualicé mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: No puedes meter un elemento que no sea un `li` dentro de un `ol`.

Answer (score 3):

También puedes embeber una lista dentro otra, incluyendo encabezados.

> 1. ## Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
>
>    1. Donec nulla dui
>    2. Integer imperdiet orci tristique
> 2. ## Sed at lectus commodo
>
>    1. Donec convallis neque nunc
>    2. Nunc lacinia in eros et luctus

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
    <ol>
      <li>Donec nulla dui</li>
      <li>Integer imperdiet orci tristique</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>Sed at lectus commodo</h1>
    <ol>
      <li>Donec convallis neque nunc</li>
      <li>Nunc lacinia in eros et luctus</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si a lo que te refieres con titulo es a las sublistas esta sería la solucion.

> Como ves, la lista se declara con la etiqueta  y finaliza con el
>   cierre de la misma `</UL>`.

De esta manera, lo que tendrias que hacer es abrir un ul por cada lista, y en caso de querer hacer otra lista inferior volver a abrir otro. Y asi sucesivamente.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Primer término de la lista
  <ul>
    <li>Sublista
    <li>Otro elemento
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hola no es lo que estaba buscando, saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez te sirva la etiqueta div

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Mi lista</h1>
  </div>
  <ol>
    <li>Elemento de la lista</li>
    <li>Elemento de la lista</li>
    <li>Elemento de la lista</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve buscando información para resolver tu duda y el problema de tu código creo que es que tenías que haberlo puesto así:

```
// esto es por si deseas mostrarlo con un encabezado h1

    <ol>
    <h1>Título de la lista</h1>
      <li>Elemento 1</li>
      <li>Elemento 2</li>
      <li>Elemento 3</li>
    </ol>


// si deseas mostrarlo como un atributo para que puedas asociarlo con tu ol, entonces:

    <ol title="Título de la lista">
      <li>Elemento 1</li>
      <li>Elemento 2</li>
      <li>Elemento 3</li>
    </ol>
```